# Tables DIV and CSS

Tags: css, html

This table is generated dynamically in PHP but for some reason it will not display the borders correctly.  There are still some aspects of CSS that stump me.  Can anyone help me understand why Firefox over rides what I have put for my element borders? Here is the generated HTML.

```
<table style="width:208px;">
<tr>
    <td colspan="7">
        <table style="width:100%; border-collapse:collapse">
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#999999; color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; height:28px;">&lt;</td>
                <td colspan="5" style="background-color:#999999; color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; height:28px;">September</td>
                <td style="background-color:#999999; color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; height:28px">&gt;</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
     </td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td style="background-color:#999999; color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; width:28px; height:28px; border:thin; border-color:#FFFFFF; border-style:solid;">S</td>
    <td style="background-color:#999999; color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; width:28px; height:28px; border:thin; border-color:#FFFFFF; border-style:solid;">M</td>
    <td style="background-color:#999999; color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; width:28px; height:28px; border:thin; border-color:#FFFFFF; border-style:solid;">T</td>
    <td style="background-color:#999999; color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; width:28px; height:28px; border:thin; border-color:#FFFFFF; border-style:solid;">W</td>
    <td style="background-color:#999999; color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; width:28px; height:28px; border:thin; border-color:#FFFFFF; border-style:solid;">T</td>
    <td style="background-color:#999999; color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; width:28px; height:28px; border:thin; border-color:#FFFFFF; border-style:solid;">F</td>
    <td style="background-color:#999999; color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; width:28px; height:28px; border:thin; border-color:#FFFFFF; border-style:solid;">S</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="7">
        <table style="width:100%; border:thin; border-color:#000000; border-style:solid; background-color:#FFFFFF; color:#000000">
            <tr style="border:thin; text-align:center;">
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;"></td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;"></td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;"></td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;"></td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;"></td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;"></td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="border:thin; text-align:center;">
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;">1</td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;">2</td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;"><div style="border-style:solid; border:thin; border-color:#008000; height:27px; width:27px">3</div></td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;"><div style="border-style:solid; border:thin; border-color:#0000FF; height:27px; width:27px">4</div></td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;">5</td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;">6</td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;">7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="border:thin; text-align:center;">
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;">8</td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;">9</td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;"><div style="border-style:solid; border:thin; border-color:#008000; height:27px; width:27px">10</div></td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;">11</td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;">12</td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;">13</td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;">14</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="border:thin; text-align:center;">
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;">15</td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;">16</td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;">17</td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;">18</td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;">19</td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;"><div style="border-style:solid; border:thin; border-color:#008000; height:27px; width:27px">20</div></td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;"><div style="border-style:solid; border:thin; border-color:#0000FF; height:27px; width:27px">21</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="border:thin; text-align:center;">
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;">22</td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;">23</td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;">24</td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;">25</td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;">26</td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;"><div style="border-style:solid; border:thin; border-color:#F5831C; height:27px; width:27px">27</div></td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;">28</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="border:thin; text-align:center;">
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;">29</td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;"><div style="border-style:solid; border:thin; border-color:#F5831C; height:27px; width:27px">30</div></td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;"></td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;"></td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;"></td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;"></td>
                <td style="border:thin; text-align:center;"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You probably want to write a rule for the <td> element so you don't have to repeat it for every single instance of that tag. That will probably help you figure out what is going on as well. You ideally don't want to mix your CSS right in with your HTML as it makes for a nightmare if you need to change something.

Comment: its actually generated in a loop using PHP so I am not actually having to type out every line

Comment: Gotcha, still harder to maintain that way though.

Comment: ...and it certainly isn't bandwidth friendly. We do still care about bandwidth, don't we?

Comment: You may have to explicitly state what kind of border you want on the <table> element. Maybe that is what is occurring?

Comment: @DavidRR  Bandwidth is still definitely a consideration but at this point I was just trying to get the concept working, but now that I have figured out where my mistake was I will work on the other issues such as performance and other styling issues.  I hadn't really thought about the bandwidth usage of this portion of project but I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complete your border attributes like  `style="border:thin solid silver;`

Hope this will help

Comment: Yeah, just "thin" won't work unless you specify the type (solid, etc.) and color.

Comment: That worked.  I thought because I was specifying them individually I didn't have to include them as a longer border statement.  Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about the error you are having but try to change border:thin  to border:2px;

thin =2px in ie but 1px in FF and Chrome

Comment: try border: 2px solid #000; and remove the other variables there may be some confusion in css